# ¿saben como colocar multiples array dentro de otro array y luego colocarlo en el main principal en java?

Tags: java, array

necesito colocar otro array dentro de este y luego colocar este dentro de mi main principal;
tambien quiero colocar varios arrays dentro de otro y colocar ese dentro de este pero por el momento solo necesito saber como colocar un array dentro de este y luego este array dentro de mi main principal

```
package proyectoJava;

public class Perro {
    
    private AccesorioPerro listaAccesorioPerro[]=new AccesorioPerro[10];
    private CuidadoHigienePerro listaCuidadoHigienePerro[]=new CuidadoHigienePerro[10];
    private int numcountAP=0;
    private int numcountCH=0;

    public Perro(AccesorioPerro AP[]) {
            this.listaAccesorioPerro=AP;
            numcountAP=AP.length;
    }
    public Perro(CuidadoHigienePerro CH[]) {
            this.listaCuidadoHigienePerro=CH;
            numcountCH=CH.length;
    }
    public void ingresar_AccesorioPerro(AccesorioPerro AP){
        listaAccesorioPerro[numcountAP]=AP;
        numcountAP++;
    }
    public void ingresar_CuidadoHigienePerro(CuidadoHigienePerro CH){
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[numcountCH]=CH;
        numcountCH++;
    }
    public AccesorioPerro getAccesorioPerro(int i){
        return listaAccesorioPerro[i];
    }
    public CuidadoHigienePerro getCuidadoHigienePerro(int j){
        return listaCuidadoHigienePerro[j];
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        AccesorioPerro listaAccesorioPerro []=new AccesorioPerro [10];
        
        listaAccesorioPerro[0]=new AccesorioPerro("Grooming Brush", 12.00);
        listaAccesorioPerro[1]=new AccesorioPerro("Pet Retractable Leash", 69.00);
        listaAccesorioPerro[2]=new AccesorioPerro("COMFORTABLE CHEST PADDING", 65.00);
        listaAccesorioPerro[3]=new AccesorioPerro("Pelota Tennis X3", 19.00);
        listaAccesorioPerro[4]=new AccesorioPerro("Plato Melamine Elevado", 35.00);
        listaAccesorioPerro[5]=new AccesorioPerro("Pelota Bombei C/Sonido Grande", 7.50);
        listaAccesorioPerro[6]=new AccesorioPerro("Nylabone Hueso Dental Masticable, Sabor Tocino Talla L", 89.90);
        listaAccesorioPerro[7]=new AccesorioPerro("Christmas Juguete Navideño De Perro Pingüino 1 unidad", 39.90);
        listaAccesorioPerro[8]=new AccesorioPerro("Mpets Cama Elevada Para Mascota L 1 unidad", 143.92);
        listaAccesorioPerro[9]=new AccesorioPerro("Dogwood 2Pk Orig/Calming Md 1 unidad", 91.90);
        
        CuidadoHigienePerro listaCuidadoHigienePerro[]=new CuidadoHigienePerro[10];
        
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[0]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Doxitel 100", 35.00);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[1]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Puppy Dental Kit", 42.00);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[2]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Bravecto 500mg para Perro 10 a 20kg - 1 Tab.", 123.80);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[3]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Nexgard 11.3mg (2kg a 4kg) - 1 tableta", 73.90);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[4]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Atrevia One Medium X 4 Tab (10-20 Kg)", 185.30);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[5]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Agua de Colonia Fresh para perros 1.00 kg", 26.90);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[6]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Pañales Macho Talla S", 24.90);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[7]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Proteggo 3m 250 Mg para Perro 4.5 10 Kg (Cja X 1 Tab) 4.10 kg", 97.52);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[8]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Guante guante de goma grooming mitt 1 unidad", 29.90);
        listaCuidadoHigienePerro[9]=new CuidadoHigienePerro("Shampoo en seco dry foam 230 ML", 29.90);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: No queda muy claro tu planteamiento si puedes explicar un poco mejor lo que quieres conseguir. Te podremos ayudar.

Comment: No se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres hacer, tampoco el diseño de tu clase. ¿Tienes el método `main` dentro de tu clase `Perro`? ¿Por qué? Luego, ¿por qué en tu clase `Perro` tienes dos constructores? ¿Piensas construir instancias de `Perro` pasándole solamente un array de `AccesorioPerro` en algunos casos y en otros pasándole un array de `CuidadoHigienePerro`? Siendo que en el método `main` creas ambas listas, la clase `Perro` puede tener un constructor que reciba ambos parámetos o tener *setters* para asignar la lista completa.

Comment: Entre *"este"*, *"este"*, *"otro"* y el *"otro"* no se entiende cuál es cual; imagina que te contestaran "pues pon ese allá con eso".

Answer (score 0):

Lo lógico, según lo que se ve en tu método `main`, es que en la clase `Perro` crees un constructor que reciba dos parámetros:

- La lista de `AccesorioPerro`
- La lista de `CuidadoHigienePerro`

Luego, estas dos propiedades:

```
private int numcountAP=0;
private int numcountCH=0;
```

Son redundantes en la clase. Si quisieras saber la cantidad de accesorios o de cuidado higiénico, lo puedes obtener con `length` en la lista de uno o de otro objeto. Pero esto no tiene sentido aquí, **porque tus listas son fijas**, otra cosa sería que quieras listas flexibles, en cuyo caso deberías usar objetos del tipo `ArrayList< AccesorioPerro>` y un `ArrayList< CuidadoHigienePerro>` a los cuales irías agregando las instancias de su tipo.

Tampoco tienen demasiado sentido los métodos de *ingresar*, por lo ya dicho, declaras de antemano en la clase las propiedades con un tamaño definido (10 elementos en la lista). Un método de *ingresar* tendría sentido en un contexto flexible, donde no sepas de antemano cuántos elementos podría tener la lista.

Por el momento, lo más lógico, siempre según lo que se ve en tu método `main`, sería una clase así:

```
public class Perro {
    
    private AccesorioPerro listaAccesorioPerro[]=new AccesorioPerro[10];
    private CuidadoHigienePerro listaCuidadoHigienePerro[]=new CuidadoHigienePerro[10];
    
    public Perro(AccesorioPerro AP[],CuidadoHigienePerro CH[]) {
            this.listaAccesorioPerro=AP;
            this.listaCuidadoHigienePerro=CH;
    }
    
    public AccesorioPerro getAccesorioPerro(int i){
        return listaAccesorioPerro[i];
    }

    public CuidadoHigienePerro getCuidadoHigienePerro(int j){
        return listaCuidadoHigienePerro[j];
    }
}
```

Aquí un [fiddle completo](https://rextester.com/LUT97808), habiendo agregado a la clase `Perro` un método `toString()` para fines de prueba.